# How can I manage my multiple wordpress websites from main website?

Tags: customization, mysql

Can this solution be used for multiple WP installations on the same site?

For example, I have multiple blogs (multiple subdirectories), i.e. mysite.com/blog1, mysite.com/blog2, mysite.com/blog3, etc. on the same site. But, I want to combine the subdirectories to use one database (and theme, and plugins, etc.) Will this solution work? How can I read my all databases my all subdirectories from main website.

I have already created WP Network and I have multiple WordPress website. I am trying to how can read all database from main website. For example: I have "watches.website.com" sub-domain and I have here some products. I want to try to call that's products from "website.com" with search. Can I do that like this? But it's not only one sub-domain. I have more sub-domains. I am trying to like pricegrabber.com or ebay.com They have sub-domains too. But they are managing all sub-domains from main website.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, and arguably several questions in one, and arguably overly broad and unanswerable in this format, but this sounds like exactly the kind of circumstance that Multisite ***was not*** meant for (Emphasis Mine):

> The sites in a multisite network **are separate**, very like the separate
>   blogs at WordPress.com. They are **not interconnected** like things in
>   other kinds of networks (even though plugins can create various kinds
>   of interconnections between the sites). **If you plan on creating sites
>   that are strongly interconnected, that share data, or share users,
>   then a multisite network *might not be the best solution*.**
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Do_you_really_need_a_network.3F

There are ways to access data from one site such as discussed in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/querying-posts-from-multiple-sites-in-a-network), and quite a few others on this site, but you are really looking at converting the network into something it was not meant to be, and that will be a lot of work.