# Create a Network of Different websites with wordpress

Tags: multisite, customization

I followed wordpress instructions of creating network of websites.
I created two subdirectories; `/site1` and `/site2`.
Why doesn't WordPress create different folders for both the subdirectories in `/theme` folder?
I want to build a network of websites with different theme but some Functionality will be same and some might not, that is why I need folders to change it.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103877/21376

Answer (score 0):

In multisite install you can control availability of themes to the sites.

- network activated theme will be available for use by all sites
- to enable theme for specific site alone go to `Network Admin` > `Sites` > `Edit` (target site) > `Themes` (tab) and enable it there

Comment: I kind of Figured, after 2 days of research wordpress multisite will not suit my requirement. Need to build something from scratch.